# UIButton not appear

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to `objective-c.`
Can anyone tell me why the button doesn't appear when I run the code.

Here is my code:

```
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    button1 = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 3, 30, 30)];
    [button1 setTitle:@"haha" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setBackgroundColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:button1];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add  `[self.view addSubview:button1];` line in `initWithNibName` before `return self;`

**other wise**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    button1 = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 3, 30, 30)];
    [button1 setTitle:@"haha" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setBackgroundColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:button1]; 
}
```

**EDIT:**

Check, are you set `@property` and `@synthesize`, properly ???

Comment: "2013-04-04 22:15:52.837 button[3548:c07] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch." Here is the information in console, can you find something?

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

Comment: add  self.YourViewController = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.YourViewController;